# dateTime values not showing up in data table. How to handle dateTime between javascript (VueJS) and php (laravel)?

Tags: javascript, php, html, vue.js, datetime

I am trying to collect user inputed date times from a modal and store them in a data table, and although I receive a success message, the dateTime values are not added to the table.

Here is my payload, of which only the state and approval appear.

> is_active
> :
> "1"
> is_approve
> :
> "1"
> justification
> :
> "sadf"
> permission_date
> :
> "2024-03-15T16:22:24.445Z"
> permissions_end_date
> :
> "2024-03-22T16:22:31.444Z"
> permissions_end_time
> :
> "03:00 PM"
> permissions_start_date
> :
> "2024-03-15T16:22:26.572Z"
> permissions_start_time
> :
> "03:00 AM"

I am pretty sure that my problem is caused by the horrible handling of dateTime between VueJS and PHP, as the payload holds all the correct information in the form of strings, it is just a matter of formatting it correctly and passing it to the data table.

Here is my controller:

```php
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Services\TdhpermissionsService;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use DateTime;

    class TdhpermissionsController extends Controller
    {
        public function __construct(
            tdhpermissionsService $tdhpermissionsService
        ) {
            $this->tdhpermissionsService = $tdhpermissionsService;
        }

        public function view()
        {
            return view('tdhpermissions.index');
        }

        //Listar registros
        public function index()
        {
            $data = $this->tdhpermissionsService
                // ->where('is_active', 1)
                ->paginate(request()->get('per_page', 10));
            return $data;
        }

        // Tomar 1 registro por $id
        public function show($id)
        {
            return $this->tdhpermissionsService->where('id', $id)->first();
        }

        // guardar registros
        public function store()
        {
            $data = $this->tdhpermissionsService->save();
            return created_responses('data', ['message' =>  'Creacion de registro exitosa', 'data' => $data]);
        }
        private function createDateTime($dateTimeString)
    {
        try {
            // Log the datetime string for debugging
            error_log("Attempting to create DateTime: DateTime: $dateTimeString");

            // Create DateTime object from ISO 8601 formatted string
            $dateTime = new DateTime($dateTimeString);

            // Return the DateTime object formatted as a string
            return $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            // Log any exceptions
            error_log("Exception in createDateTime: " . $e->getMessage());
            throw $e;
        }
    }

        //actualizar registros
        public function update($id)
        {
            $entity = $this->tdhpermissionsService->where('id', $id)->first();
            $data = $this->tdhpermissionsService->update($entity);
            return created_responses('data', ['message' =>  'Actualizacion de registro exitosa', 'data' => $data]);
        }

        // eliminar registros
        public function destroy($id)
        {
            $entity = $this->tdhpermissionsService->where('id', $id)->first();
            $data = $this->tdhpermissionsService->delete($entity);
            return created_responses('data', ['message' =>  'Eliminacion de registro exitosa', 'data' => $data]);
        }
    }
```

I have tried two different migrations, one with type String for the values and one with type date, but both have resulted in the same error.

Here is the one with type string:

```php
$table->String("permission_date");
$table->String("permission_start_date");
$table->String("permission_end_date");
$table->String("permission_start_time");
$table->String("permission_end_time");
$table->String("justification");
```

and the one with type date time:

```php
$table->date("permission_date");
$table->dateTime("permission_start_date");
$table->dateTime("permission_end_date");
$table->dateTime("permission_start_time");
$table->dateTime("permission_end_time");
$table->String("justification");
```

Here is my modal inside which the user is setting these values.

```js
<script>
import { FormMixin } from '../../../../core/mixins/form/FormMixin';
import AppLibrary from '../../../Helpers/AppLibrary';
import { ModalMixin } from '../../../Mixins/ModalMixin';
import { DatePicker } from 'v-calendar/lib/v-calendar.umd';


export default {
    name: "tdhpermissionsModal",
    extends: AppLibrary,
    mixins: [FormMixin, ModalMixin],
    props: {
        tableId: String
    },
    data() {
        return {
            preloader: false,
            inputs: {

            },
            activeLists: [
                    {id: '0', value: "Inactivo"},
                    {id: '1', value: "Activo"},
                ],
            modalId: 'tdhpermissions-edit-Modal',
            modalTitle: this.$t('Crear nuevas permissiones'),
        }

    },
    created() {
        if (this.selectedUrl) {
            this.modalTitle = this.$t('edit');
            this.preloader = true;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submit() {

            this.save
                (this.inputs);
        },
        afterSuccess(response) {
            this.$toastr.s(response.data.message);
            this.$hub.$emit('reload-' + this.tableId);
        },

        afterSuccessFromGetEditData(response) {
            this.inputs = response.data;
            this.preloader = false;
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
<modal :modal-id="modalId" :title="modalTitle" :preloader="preloader" @submit="submit" @close-modal="closeModal">
    <template slot="body">
        <app-overlay-loader v-if="preloader" />
        <form class="mb-0" :class="{ 'loading-opacity': preloader }" ref="form" 
            :data-url='selectedUrl 
            ? `masterdata/tdhpermissions/${inputs.id}` 
            : `masterdata/tdhpermissions`'>
            <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
                <label class="col-md-12">
                    {{ $t('permission_date') }}
                </label>
                <app-input class="col-sm-8"
                           type="date"
                           v-model="inputs.permission_date"
                           :placeholder="$t('select_valid_date')"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
                <label class="col-md-12">
                    {{ $t('permission_start_date') }}
                </label>
                <app-input class="col-sm-8"
                           type="date"
                           v-model="inputs.permission_start_date"
                           :placeholder="$t('select_valid_date')"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
                <label class="col-md-12">
                    {{ $t('permission_start_time') }}
                </label>
                <app-input class="col-sm-8"
                           type="time"
                           v-model="inputs.permission_start_time"
                           :placeholder="$t('select_valid_time')"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
                <label class="col-md-12">
                    {{ $t('permission_end_date') }}
                </label>
                <app-input class="col-sm-8"
                           type="date"
                           v-model="inputs.permission_end_date"
                           :placeholder="$t('select_valid_date')"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
                <label class="col-md-12">
                    {{ $t('permission_end_time') }}
                </label>
                <app-input class="col-sm-8"
                           type="time"
                           v-model="inputs.permission_end_time"
                           :placeholder="$t('select_valid_time')"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
                <label for="inputs_name" class="col-md-12">
                    {{ $t('Justification') }}
                </label>
                <app-input id="inputs_name" class="col-sm-9" type="textarea" 
                    v-model="inputs.justification"
                    :placeholder="$t('textarea_field')" :required="true" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row align-items-center " > <!--stlye="margin bottom: x px;"-->
                <label class="col-sm-3 mb-0">
                    {{ $t('Approval') }}
                </label>
                <app-input class="col-sm-9"
                           type="radio"
                           v-model="inputs.is_approve"
                           :list="activeLists"/>
            </div>
             
            <div class="form-group row align-items-center ">
                <label class="col-sm-3 mb-0">
                    {{ $t('Estado') }}
                </label>
                <app-input class="col-sm-9"
                           type="radio"
                           v-model="inputs.is_active"
                           :list="activeLists"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </template>
</modal>
</template>
```

Service:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Services\Core\BaseService;
use App\Models\Tdhpermissions as Entity;

class TdhpermissionsService extends BaseService
{
    public function __construct(Entity $entity)
    {
        $this->model = $entity;
    }
    public function update(Entity $entity)
    {
        $entity->fill(request()->all());
        $this->model = $entity;
        $entity->save();
        return $entity;
    }
    public function delete(Entity $entity)
    {
        return $entity->delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: `permissions_start_date` in your payload is not the same as `permission_start_date` in your table

Comment: @aynber thank you for the reply! Can you explain this further? How is it different?

Comment: `permissions` on payload -- plural. `permission` on table -- single. Simple typo

Comment: @anyber wow! Can't believe I didn't catch that thank you! I will update my question accordingly

Comment: You can use `Carbon::parse()` on the string to create a Carbon instance, which you can then pass into your query builder. Laravel knows what to do with it, or you can format it the way you want.

Comment: @Trinky - you said "Can't believe I didn't catch that thank you! I will update my question accordingly" does this mean you have a solution to your problem? If so either post your own answer or delete the question; at the moment it's still showing as "unanswered".

Comment: And for next time, please only show code relevant to the question; have a look at the help topic [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There's no need to include all the html, and code for the `view`,`index`, and `show` functions if the problem is in the `store` code :)

Comment: @aynber in that case do you think it would be better to use the migration with dateTime types? Also, do you know why my current strings aren't being posted to the data table in the first place? Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: It's hard to tell what might be breaking, since it's all running through `$tdhpermissionsService`, which you don't show. You'll probably have to do some troubleshooting.  My favorite troubleshooting tool on the Laravel side is `Log::info()` which will log whatever you place into it into the log files in `storage/logs`.

Comment: @aynber Amazing I will experiment with that. I have also included my $tdhpermissionsService in case that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because JavaScript and PHP handle dates differently, in order to pull them from the back end to the front end it is necessary to convert the way of showing this information in the table formatter itself. Here is an example:

```
{ 
    title: this.$t('permission_date'),
    type: 'custom-html',
    key: 'permission_date',
    modifier: (value) => {
        return moment(String(value)).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    }
}
```